# Application properly deployed on Wildfly but showing blank page

Tags: spring, cxf, jsf-2.2, wildfly-8

I have a deployed application in Wildfly v8 and v9 which is running on modules JSF, WebServices. It is using the default class loading sequence and I am not doing any additional configuration. The issue that I am facing is that the deployment has success fully completed but when I access the webpage it is blank.

Has anyone experienced this before. Please assist.

Thanks.

Comment: Rightclick page in browser, *View page source*. What exactly do you see?

Comment: It is giving me a whole blank page

Comment: Press F12 in browser, *Network*. What exactly do you see in the response?

Comment: Is it blank or 404 ? Also provide some code to explain your case

Comment: @YouYou: code..? How should OP know which code exactly you mean?

Comment: @BalusC Ok I got you ,I'm expecting the minimum configuration files web.xml,pom.xml and the page its self

Comment: The page is blank. Not 404. I am getting the output from the Container JSF cycle showing that the deployment was successful and a page was rendered back:

Comment: 18:36:35,519 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.facelets.factory] (default task-5) Creating Facelet for: file:/C:/Java/wildfly10/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp/tempa1f81ecf119328b6/content-a4b11196f6ac47e3/templates/layoutmenu.xhtml
18:36:35,529 FINE  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.timing] (default task-5)  [TIMING] - [114ms] : Execution time for phase (including any PhaseListeners) -> RENDER_RESPONSE 6

Comment: The content of the files is too long to paste it in comments section how do I send the info